# Netbeans me crea JpaControllers vacios

Tags: java, sql, netbeans, jpa, controller

estoy empezando con lo que es java. Y me encontre con este problema!
Tengo declaradas las @Identity, y la persistencia. Pero cuando declaro el controlador, puedo seleccionar la identidad de clases (me aparecen todas) pero una vez creada. Esta vacio, sin ningun metodo (creacion destruccion, etc). Si bien entiendo el concepto, pierdo mucho tiempo escribiendo cada linea para cada entidad.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
No se como solucionarlo. Gracias.